# How to create a relation between 3 entities in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to build a chat application with EF Core which consists of 3 entities: `user, chat & message`.

Each user should contain a list of all chats he is in.
Each chat should contain the two users who are in the chat and all messages, sent in the chat.
Each message should contain the chat, the message is sent in and the user who sent the message.

Those are my current entities:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public User User1 { get; set; }
    public User User2 { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public User Sender { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
}
```

I tried many things but nothing worked.

Comment: Those are entities, not models. All EF Core tutorials show how to define relations between entities. In fact, by using the `Messages`, `Chats` and `Chat` properties EF Core itself will generate those relations based on the names and types. What have you tried and what didn't work? What's the actual problem? Do the tables exist or are you trying to create them using migrations?

Comment: Be advised, though, that EF Core not always auto-gens what's best or what you expect. Always check migrations before pushing your changes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used those Entities like they are posted here. When creating a migration the following error occurrs: `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Chat.User1' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Comment: Are Chats only ever between 2 Users?

Comment: Post that in the question itself, and actually explain what you want to do. The error is pretty clear though and tells you what you need to do - configure that particular relation in the DbContext's `OnModelCreating` method

Comment: @Fildor I wanted to implement a group chat in the future, however I didn't post it here to avoid complexity.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's my problem, I don't know how to configure the correct relation, that's what I'm asking. The tutorials I found only show relation between 2 Entities.

Comment: My guess would be to use within `Chat` a `public List<User> Users {get; set;}` instead of the two explicit users. In that case you directly have group chats (in your model) and the mapping should also automatically detect everything needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to

```
public class Chat
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users{ get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

And you've got a simple Many-to-Many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Hello This is the right way to make your relationships whit EF Core.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
         this.Chats = new HashSet<Chat>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Chat> Chats  { get; set; }
 
}

public class Chat
{
    public Chat()
    {
         this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
         this.Messages = new HashSet<Message>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string ChatId { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
}
```

Уou can access the Users through your Users collection in Chat. Also you can access Chats of current user through Chats property in User